# How to use CMake to make a project with different toolsets for each configuration

Tags: cmake, mfc

I have a .sln with many MFC projects. All of them have at least 3 configurations, such as Debug90, Debug140 and Debug142, each has its own platform toolset, for example,  Debug90 use toolset v90, Debug140 use toolset v140. How can I use CMake to set this target property?
I try to use

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug140>:"
        "v140"
    ">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug142>:"
        "v141"
    ">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug90>:"
        "v90"
    ">"
)
```

but it's error beacause no supporting generator-expression in VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET